# How to disable insert in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design

Is there any way do disable the insertion of an Entity in Entity Framework?

I'm using DDD and, on a specific bounded context, some required database fields of the users table doesn't make sense (inside this context). So, I want to remove them from the User entity, but in doing so I loose the ability to save a **new** user to database. Which is ok, since, in this context, I shouldn't create users.

My first thought was to disable the insertion (but allow updates) on the User Entity.

Is it feasible? Or, is there another solution to this situation?

Comment: Sounds to me you are already protected by virtue of that exception, no? I find investing in this kind of "protection" to be a waste of time. Seems to me the 'identity & access mgmt' BC should provide you with the necessary query methods & representation.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But, when the effort isn't big, I always prefer to have compile time errors instead of runtime ones.

Comment: Also, imagine another developer trying to figure out why a simple insert is throwing an exception. It can take a long time until he realizes the real problem.

Comment: Communication seems essential to me. But that's besides the point. What's wrong here is that you are (re)using EF for what should essentially be a readonly view of the user data. You are allowing people to access the Object/DbContext which they shouldn't be able to in the first place. You're missing a level of abstraction that is communicating that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable insertion but you can find if any entity is marked for insertion and fire exception in such case.

The best place to do such handling is in override of `SaveChanges` method:

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{
    if (ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                          .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                          .Select(e => e.Entity)
                          .OfType<User>()
                          .Any())
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("User cannot be inserted");
    }

    return base.SaveChanges(options);
}
```

This is runtime behavior but because EF doesn't differ between modification operations (all are inside single `SaveChanges`) you cannot detect inserting at compile time.

Comment: Thanks! At least I can provide a more meaningful error if someone tries to insert a User.

Comment: It would be nicer if I could extend DbSet to Create a ReadOnlyDbSet and override the `Add` method. But the guys behind Entity Framework decided to make the constructor internal :/

Comment: It would not help because there are other ways how to insert a user without ever calling `Add` on the set.